# How to remove events from nicEditor + emberjs

Tags: ember.js, nicedit

I am working on an Ember.js - based platform, where I use nicEdit. Here is my code

```
RichHTMLView = Ember.TextArea.extend({
    id: null,
    editor: null,
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var view = this;

        view.id = this.get("elementId");

        view.editor = new nicEditor({
                buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','right','center','justify', 'link', 'ul', 'ol']
        }).panelInstance(view.id);

        //When the editor looses focus the content of the editor is passed to descr
        view.editor.addEvent('blur',function(){
            view.get('controller').set('descr',view.getViewContent());
        });

        //So the editor looks nice
        $('.nicEdit-panelContain').parent().width('100%');
        $('.nicEdit-panelContain').parent().next().width('100%');
    },
    getViewContent: function(){
        var view = this,
            inlineEditor = view.editor.instanceById(view.id);
        return inlineEditor.getContent();
    },
    willClearRender: function(){
        var view = this;
    }

});
```

So this works nicely as long as I am on the page which hosts the view, but if I transition to another route, the view has some leftovers, namely the editor is destroyed, but I assume that nicEdit keeps track of event bindings, so I end up with the `blur` event being bound to editor, which is `undefined` in the new context, as the view does not exist.

My best guess is that I need to somehow unbind the editor in the `willClearRender`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I got no reply and [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) is abandoned I made some changes to the source-code in order to deal with this issue by adding `removeEvent` to `bkEvent`:

```
removeEvent: function(A, B){

if (B){
    this.eventList = this.eventList || {};
    this.eventList[A] = this.eventList[A] || [];
    this.eventList[A].splice(this.eventList[A].indexOf(B),1);
}
```

Then I can remove the event in `willClearRender`:

```
view.editor.removeEvent('blur',view.onBlur);
```

Be aware that I've not tested it with multiple editors, as my needs do not require, but if you have multiple editors with the same callback the behavior is not defined.